# Drawing lines on google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am able to draw the lines on the maps using the following code:

```js
var flightPlanCoordinates1 = [
    { lat: 22.53412218657744, lng: -95.4580076783896 },
    { lat: 25.265810430433756, lng: -96.51269517838955 },
    { lat: 24.308304859959954, lng: -92.4916990846396 },
    { lat: 28.150714091845007, lng: -94.07373033463955 },
    { lat: 26.530793950651773, lng: -89.92089830338955 },
    { lat: 25.5635039073037, lng: -87.63574205338955 },
    { lat: 26.491469591982202, lng: -85.30664049088955 },
    { lat: 28.65323578152034, lng: -86.80078111588955 },
    { lat: 28.845876611067364, lng: -88.91015611588955 },
    { lat: 27.587415049297192, lng: -88.33886705338955 },
    { lat: 25.84068541364038, lng: -94.00781236588955 }
];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates1,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
```

But in a real application as we are getting data from db and populating it , I am not able to get the lines on the map 
So, here is the object declaration and initialization:

```js
flightPlanCoordinates = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonOut.length; i++) {
    jsonCor["lat"] = jsonOut[i]["lat"];
    jsonCor["long"] = jsonOut[i]["long"];
    flightPlanCoordinates.push(jsonCor);
}

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
```

The data in the object is as below:

```js
0: Object
lat: 23.222417047162825
long: -95.45800767838955
__proto__: Object
1:Object
```

so on which is exactly in the example shown above.

What is the problem with the object which is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < jsonOut.length; i++) {
    flightPlanCoordinates.push({
        lat: parseFloat(jsonOut[i]["lat"]),
        lng: parseFloat(jsonOut[i]["long"]
    });
}
```

Firstly make the structure of your coordinates match what you were doing originally, i.e. `{lat: x, lng: y}` instead of `{lat, x, long: y}`.

Secondly because you're reading it from JSON, you probably also need to do `parseFloat()` on the values, otherwise they're likely to be strings.